# Django Compressor : cache messing up

Tags: django, django-compressor

I have a webapp using django-compressor for js, css and less minification.

I'm using `COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True` because I'm using django compressor to build a less file containing import to other files (otherwise django compressor does not rebuild files if make change in core.less):

```
// base.html
{% compress css %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/less" media="all" href="{% static 'less/main.less' %}" />
{% endcompress %}

// main.less
@import "core.less";
@import "variables.less";
@import "utils.less";
@import "sidebar.less";
```

I am running into the following issue: i have the following .css files in `assets/CACHE/css`:

```
2601cbccb2ae.css
52a7aa59f552.css
729b9866970c.css
```

They are all corresponding to a modification of my core.less file. The issue is that when I log in my webapp, it seems Django-Compress {%compress%} use all those file and not only the last one. So sometimes I have the good design, and if I refresh I got the old one...

```
// First time the page is ok:
<link href="/static/CACHE/css/2601cbccb2ae.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

// After reloading I got the old design
<link href="/static/CACHE/css/52a7aa59f552.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Each time I refresh the file changes... So I assume there is something related to django compressor cache but I have really no idea how to solve this...

If you guys have an idea, feel free to help me.

Comment: I think `@import` is not well supported by django-compressor: http://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/?highlight=import#recommendations